# Why am I unable to login to my centos/7 box using Putty?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, putty, centos7, gssapi

I'm using Win10, Putty, Vagrant and Virtualbox.

I set everything up the same way I did for my ubuntu/trusty box (which worked perfectly) but I am getting this error after trying to login to my centos box:

Disconnected: no supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey, gssapi-keyex, gssapi-with-mic)

I've looked through a bunch of threads here and elsewhere, but haven't found the answer to my question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use password authentication, you can type :

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password  user@IP
```

To make it persistent, edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config, then restart ssh service

Answer (score 1):

Seems your centOS is configured to use SSH key for login. 
It wont ask for any password, you should have SSH key to login to the OS.
And convert that SSH key to putty compatible format and add the ssh key in putty then try to login.